# Reduce delay while selecting option in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk, jquery-mobile-select

I have my application installed on an Android Device **Samsung S4** which is built using `Intel XDK`. I have a select dropdown in the form having **40 options**. When i tap on an option to choose, it chooses the option instantly but takes 2 seconds of delay before closing the **opened options popup**.

I have tried the following fix but it did not work as expected.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = true; //i also changed to false and didn't work either
});
```

Is there any other fix i can apply to reduce or remove the lag between choosing an option and closing the option box?

Comment: Note that options in none _native_ menu, options are converted into buttons or checkboxes. When you choose an option, it updates styles of selected _button_, update _selectmenu_ widget, close _popup_. Use native dropdown menu if you want faster results.

Comment: By native dropdown menu you mean `<select>` with custom css?

Comment: No, just `<select>` but it will be styled. Options will look native with no popup/dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Although this didn't work for me

```
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
```

But adding `data-native-menu="false"` to the select element it worked fine

```
<select name="year" id="year" data-theme="a" data-native-menu="false">
```